# How to add 2 object type into one object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have stuck with one of the logic please help  me out. I have 2 object (Value, Value1). these 2 object are of type

```
object {System.Collections.Generic.List<Address>}
```

I want to merge the 2 object into one and i want to set the value into main object Customers.

Here is the code:

```
foreach (var res in result)
{
   var Value = GetResponse();
   var referenceData = ((IEnumerable<object>)value).Cast<object>().ToList();
   if (referenceData.Count() > 0)
   {
     var prop = res.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == referenceData.FirstOrDefault().GetType().Name);
     var value1 = prop.GetValue(res, null);
     var abc = ((IEnumerable<object>)value1).Cast<object>().ToList();
     if (abc.Count() > 0)
     {
         // Here i need to set the both value and value1 to value only 
     }

     prop.SetValue(res, Convert.ChangeType(value, prop.PropertyType));
   }
}
```

In the above code result is the `List<Customer>` .Value and value1 is `object{List<Address>}`

Comment: What to you meant by "merging two objects into one"?

Comment: @FaisalM, I want to merge Value and value1 to Value object type. How can i do that?.Merge means combing the values

Comment: @FaisalM, I am edited the question and cleary mention what those values are also. In the last line.

Comment: Do you want to merge two lists of type `List<Address>` and create one? You could use use `List.AddRange`

Comment: @FaisalM, I can add like that but it is of object{List<Address>}. so i am unable to do add range

Comment: @prasanthi, I'm not very clear about your ask, I can try to help, initiate a chat with me when you're back

Comment: @Clint13, i am back. Can we initiate chat.